# An inequality for continuous function on unit interval with continuous first derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a function on the unit interval that is continuous and has a continuous first derivative f' . Show that $$Sup_{0\le x,y\le1} |f(x)-f(y)| \le ||f'||_2 $$
It is a homework for Hilbert spaces and its name is sobolev's inequality . But i haven't seen it with this name before.
Can you help me to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for any $x,y\in [0,1]$, the fundamental theorem of analysis gives that 
$$f(x)-f(y)=\int_x^y f'(t)\mathrm dt.$$
In order to control $|f(x)-f(y)|$, use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the fact that $\sqrt{|x-y|}\leqslant 1$.